# SyncFusion multiselect wildcard search ejs .NET control

Tags: c#, .net, ejs, syncfusion

Is there a way to do a wildcard search using multi-select control? It allows choosing the fields displayed in the dropdown.

I wanted to implement wildcard search, i.e, abc* as a search string and it has to display all the records starting with abc. I must use other controls to achieve this. But doing it for the scope of the application.

```
<ejs-multiselect id="test" dataSource="@Model.testGroup" value="Model.test" mode="Box" allowFiltering="true" change="onchange" filtering="onfiltering">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement as custom filtering feature by using our filtering event.
Find the code example here:

```
<ejs-multiselect id="list" placeholder="Select countries" query="@query" dataSource="@data"
                        allowFiltering="true" filtering="onFiltering">
            <e-multiselect-fields text="Name" value="Code"></e-multiselect-fields>
        </ejs-multiselect>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    function onFiltering(e) {
        var query = new ej.data.Query();
        // frame the query based on search string with filter type.
        query = (e.text !== '') ? query.where('Name', 'startswith', e.text, true) : query;
        // pass the filter data source, filter query to updateData method.
        e.updateData(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)), query);
    }
</script>
```

To know more about the custom filtering, refer to the below documentation and online demo sample.
Online demo sample: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/MultiSelect/Filtering#/fluent
documentation link: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/multi-select/filtering